# Trying to implement jQuery plugins, failing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I've yet to successfully call a jQuery function that I loaded through a separate .js file and I've checked and triple-checked for hours and I still can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. For example, this plugin: http://vitalets.github.io/combodate/

Here's the code on my page:

```
<input type="text" id="date" data-format="DD-MM-YYYY h:mm a" data-template="DD / MM / YYYY     hh : mm a" name="date" value="21-12-2012 8:30 pm">
<script>
$(function(){
$('#date').combodate();
});
</script>
```

Result: nothing. I honestly can't see what's wrong. I've checked and checked it against the example code in the plugin's docs and tried numerous different syntaxes. I tried noConflict. I have similar results for *all* jQuery plugins that I try to implement via script tags.

To cover my bases: yes, jquery.js is loaded, the plugin is loaded. The plugin also depends on moment.js, and I have that loaded. Here's the relevant part of my footer just in case you see any problems there.

```
<script src="assets/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="owl-carousel/owl.carousel.js"></script>
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=geometry&v=3.7"></script>
<script src="assets/js/maplace-0.1.3.js"></script>
<script src="moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="combodate.js"></script>
```

All those src links are good, I checked them after loading the page.

Like I said, this happens every time. But I also tried this exact code in JSfiddle (even checked to make sure that it didn't conflict with Bootstrap, which, according to JSfiddle at least, it didn't) and it works soooooo... is there some kind of server setting or something, or some attribute I need to put in the script tag? Thanks for any help.

Comment: what errors get thrown?

Comment: do those three lines of code you pasted execute before those `script` declarations on your footer? if so it would throw a `$ is undefined` error and not do anything

Comment: You made a jsfiddle but did not post the link? What is the code to call the plugin?

Comment: @NicolásStraubValdivieso I was getting $ is undefined in the console, yeah. So I put the script declarations at the top of the page and that fixed it. Thanks! But I'm confused because I thought I'd already tried that (guess not!), but also because I've often been told that JS scripts should be declared at the end of the page with pretty much no exceptions.

Comment: yeah, that's true. also true is if you try to access a variable (`$` in this case) before referencing it, you'll get the undefined error :). I'd just put the `$(function(){})` script below the other ones. that would solve the issue

Answer (score 0):

We going to diagnose this in two face

1. Use latest jquery library and if doesn't workout
2. Use latest jquery library and remove owl.carousel.js, maplace-0.1.3.js and google map Api and try again. if it workout, that means their is conflict among the libraries.